# Scroll view and Content view height mismatching at run time

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I am using `scrollview` and `contentView`.

In below image yellow colour is `scrollview` and blue one in `contentView`. `scrollView` scrolls correctly but the issue of height mismatch height because of the last `textView` and button `userInteraction` is disabled.

my view hierarchy is,

1.`UIView`

2.`UIScrollView`

3.`ContentView`

4.On `contentView` other UIElements added.

anyone faced this issue, anyone could help me to solve this issue. Thanks..

[image]

Comment: provide screenshot of your storyboard so that the actual hierarchy can be traced

Comment: thanks for your response, https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyzY6.png -> this one is view hierarchy in storyboard.

Comment: so you are adding the components programmatically in the content view?

Comment: yes i am adding programmaticaly.

Comment: Then use autolayout only. why are you giving constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the constraints of the UI Elements you have in contentView.

If the constraints were correct, the elements won't leave contentView.

Also, don't keep your contentView's height as constant. Let it grow by giving vertical spacing between "Submit" button and contentView.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your response...Finally that issue got fixed by referring this one...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rVXhbBfFjo. thanks a lot.